# How do I ssh with multiple hops using passwords?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, login, password

I wanted to `ssh` from `server1` and reach `server3` via `server2`.

This can be done using:

```
ssh -t user2@server2 ssh user3@server3
```

But how can I achieve this when `server2` and `server3` have **password logins?**

Constraints:

1) **Not going to type in passwords**

2) **I can't use ssh keys in this case**

Comment: It's not clear why the particular example you're giving does not work with password/interactive logins. It should actually work. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Could you please post the command (where you are using passwords)  which is working for you

Comment: It's exactly your command, except that I'm using my user and host names ;-)

Comment: How are you passing passwords ? I am interested in knowing that. That is the whole point of this question

Comment: I'm typing them in. If you're using sshpass or similar, or want to instrument it with `expect`, then mention that explicitly.

Comment: Ohh totally forgot that people can type in passwords as well. Will edit the questions 

Comment: passwords are so 20th Century ... I realize this is probably some learning exercise however I must stress all ssh connections should use private/public keys and lock down your ssh server to disallow passwords ... every ssh server connected to the internet is under attack every minute of every day and using passwords is leaving yourself wide open to abuse

Comment: LOL, does ssh supports reCAPTCHAs? That would certainly shut me out for good -- Google's artificial stupidity always treats me (a human) as a bot. Seriously, if you want an `expect(1)` solution for multiple ssh password auth, then say so explicitly. That would be much more useful for people coming here via searches.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `-t` option with each subsequent `ssh`, except for the last:

```
ssh -t user1@server1 ssh -t user2@server2 ssh user3@server3
```

If possible, better use `-J` (`ProxyJump`) instead of embedded ssh commands:

```
ssh -J user1@server1,user2@server2 user3@server3
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this. The quick and dirty one I would use is to tunnel from `server1 -> server2` and then use that tunnel to go `server1 -> server3`

```
ssh -L localhost:2222:server3:22 server2
```

Here we are saying:
ssh to `server2`...
 any traffic that shows up on the **L**ocal side of the tunnel on localhost port 2222...
 put through the tunnel..
on the far side, send that traffic to server3 port 22

Then from another window:

```
ssh -p2222 localhost
```

That should prompt you for the password on server3.

Comment: That tunnel trick is exactly what the `-J` option of ssh is doing, but without an extra listening socket. But it's not clear for me why OP's example doesn't work -- it works for me.